# Python json output KeyError: 'Link Annotations - dynamic json

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, api

I have a json output where the output is dynamic, sometimes there is the object below, but sometimes is empty so no dict is available in the output and create an error when the output missing this object: KeyError: 'Link Annotations'".

In my python code I'm using this access and it's fine but just when the object is available - > `Link = process["Link Annotations"]`

```
"full": {
"Link Annotations": {
  "E.460.15763456.34": [
    {
      "Link": "http://link",
      "Dimensions": [
        28.5,
        2773,
        307.5,
        2789.5
      ]
    },
    {
      "Link": "http://link",
      "Dimensions": [
        28.5,
        2756.5,
        255.75,
        2773
      ]
    },
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: When "Link Annotations" is not in json output I receive: KeyError: 'Link Annotations'"

Comment: Then first check if the key "Link Annotations" is in the dictionary.

Comment: It doesn't make it very easy to help you if you don't show us your code. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] so that we can reproduce the problem. See [ask] for more information on asking good questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you want to do if `Link Annotations` is missing.

To avoid errors you can use `get` method:

```py
Link = process.get("Link Annotations", None)
if not Link:
    print("Key: 'Link Annotations' is missing.")
    # your code here
```

or `try`, `except` block:

```py
try:
    Link = process["Link Annotations"]
except KeyError:
    print("Key: 'Link Annotations' is missing.")
    # your code here
```

But how to handle if key is missing is up to you.

Comment: Thanks I resolved it using this comment: Then first check if the key "Link Annotations" is in the dictionary.